# Set next object in list iterator

Tags: c++, list, loops

```
list<Book>::iterator pos;
    pos = books.begin();

    books.begin()->setPrevBook(NULL);

    for (pos = books.begin(); pos != books.end(); pos++)
    {
        cout << book.getTitle() << "\n"
            << book.getAuthor() << "\n"
            << book.getISBN() << "\n"

            //I'd like to set the next and previous books here
            //<< book.setNextBook()
              //<<book.setPrevBook()
            << "******************************" << endl;
    }
```

This is my iterator for my books, my program goes through the loop until the user tells it to stop and it then prints out all the books.

I also have this code for my books

```
void Book::setNextBook(Book* nextBookParam)
{
    nextBook = nextBookParam;
}

Book* Book::getNextBook() const
{
    return nextBook;
}

void Book::setPrevBook(Book* prevBookParam)
{
    prevBook = prevBookParam;
}

Book* Book::getPrevBook() const
{
    return prevBook;
}
```

What i would like to do in my list iterator is, as it completes adding a new book, add the next book to the book thats about to be added and the previous book to the one thats just been added. Essentially, i would like to link all the books together.

Is there a way i can do this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's the relationship between `pos` and `book`? Didn't you mean `*pos` when you said `book`?

Comment: Well i want my iterator pos to store the objects in a Book list. I'm not too sure what you mean by *pos Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: What you're showing now is looping over an existing list of books and printing them all out. There's no "user telling to stop." Are you asking how to create the list from user input? If so, that's totally not clear from the question.

Comment: Well i have that userInput above that. I keep asking the user to enter in details of books until i press q, after which it gets to the block of code in my question, so ive created books already, i just then want the list iterator to link all the books together. e.g When i debug and i add 2 books, the debugger shows that the previous  book of the second book is = NULL, i would like it to show that the previous book is = book1 etc

Comment: I've tried writing an answer, but your question is still very unclear. Perhaps you could post more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to re-create the doubly-linked list `books` with pointers stored inside your `Book` class. That seems a bit of a waste of effort, but if you need it, you have two options.

1. You could use an extra iterator in the loop to point to the "last" book:

   ```
   list<Book>::iterator pos, last;
   books.begin()->setPrevBook(NULL);
   for (pos = books.begin(); pos != books.end(); ++pos)
   {
       cout << pos->getTitle() << "\n"
           << pos->getAuthor() << "\n"
           << pos->getISBN() << "\n"
           << "******************************" << endl;
       if (pos != books.begin())
       {
         last->setNextBook(&*pos);
         pos->setPrevBook(&*last);
       }
       last = pos;
   }
   books.back().setNextBook(NULL);
   ```
2. Use a pointer to the last book instead of an iterator:

   ```
   list<Book>::iterator pos;
   books.begin()->setPrevBook(NULL);
   Book *last = NULL;
   for (pos = books.begin(); pos != books.end(); ++pos)
   {
       cout << pos->getTitle() << "\n"
           << pos->getAuthor() << "\n"
           << pos->getISBN() << "\n"
           << "******************************" << endl;
       if (last)
       {
         last->setNextBook(&*pos);
         pos->setPrevBook(last);
       }
       last = &*pos;
   }
   books.back().setNextBook(NULL);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
auto book = books->begin();
book ->setPreviousBook(NULL);
auto prev = book;
++book;
while(book != books->end()) {
    book->setPreviousBook(&*prev);
    prev->setNextBook(&*book);
    ++book;
    ++prev;
}

prev->setNextBook(NULL);
```